# Same image appear in 3 different div's randomly with seconds interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 colored divs. I want one image to appear in one of the 3 DIVs chosen randomly. E.g. if image is in the first div, then second and third DIVs should be still visible but empty. After 3 seconds the image should disappear and re-appear in another randomly chosen DIV.

At the moment i have only CSS and HTML.

CSS

```
.first {
    float: left;
    width:33%;
    display:block;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    padding:30px 0;
}
.second {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    display:block;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
    padding:30px 0;
}
.third {
    float: right;
    width: 34%;
    display:block;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    padding:30px 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="first"><img class="img_first" src="img.png"/></div>
<div class="second"><img class="img_second" src="img.png"/></div>
<div class="third"><img class="img_third" src="img.png"/></div>
```

Comment: This needs some extra context. Where does the image come from? Do you want to load it asynchronously? Do you really want to hide two of the boxes? Why not show only one in the first place? What is the reason for this whole application? You're describing a way you want to work but maybe there's a better way to solve the underlying problem.

Comment: I don't want to hide boxes, i only want to hide the images on 2 of the div's while the one is showing the image. The reason behind this is more like a game. "Catch the image to move on to the next level". Sorry for my bad english if it's hard to understand :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are asking for. Select a random div and show that div's nested img.

HTML

```
<div class="first"><img src="duh.jpg"></div>
<div class="second"><img src="duh.jpg"></div>
<div class="third"><img src="duh.jpg"></div>
```

Js/ Jquery

```
var active = 1;
var myNum = 1;
setInterval(function(){
    while( active == myNum){
        myNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3)) + 1;
    }
    active = myNum;
    switch(active) {
    case 1:
        $('.first img').show();
        $('.second img, .third img').hide();
        break;
    case 2:
        $('.second img').show();
        $('.first img, .third img').hide();
        break;        
    case 3:
        $('.third img').show();
        $('.first img, .second img').hide();
        break;
    } 
}, 1000);
```

Here is a working [Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f0ohd6p4/1/)

Comment: This is exactly what i need. Is it possible to create that it doesn't choose same div again? Sometimes it just stuck on the div for 3x times so in total make 3x more seconds :P

Comment: I updated the code so it doesn't select the same div over and over.

Comment: Much tidier solution than mine! +1

Comment: You are godlike, sir! Last question, how is it possible to create that it doesn't show all 3 images from the beginning? So onload it already starts with only 1 img and 2,3 hidden. Will accept your answer withing couple of minutes!

Comment: If you can change the div's class names so they are all the same, you could make this a lot shorter [example](http://jsfiddle.net/f0ohd6p4/2/)

Comment: set the display to none in the css to hide the images on page load.    .first img, .second img, .third img{ display:none; }

Comment: Quick question -- I used a similar code as yours for this, but in mine, the div that is currently showing always moves over to the left position instead of staying in it's original position. I can't tell what in our codes causes this difference. https://jsfiddle.net/snookieordie/zcf56av3/

Comment: @snookieordie You need to make the divs a container and change the visibility of an item inside of it so the structure doesn't collapse into nothing. [Here is a jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/zcf56av3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is the best solution to your problem but should give you an idea as to how you can approach it...

```
function cycleImages()
{    
    var first = $('.img_first')
    var second = $('.img_second');
    var third = $('.img_third');

    if(first.css('display') == 'block'){
        // Show second image
        second.show()

        // Hide previous images
        first.hide()
        third.hide()
    }

    else if(second.css('display') == 'block'){
        // Populate third div
        third.show()

        // Clear previous images
        first.hide()
        second.hide()
    }

    else if(third.css('display') == 'block'){
        // Populate first div
        first.show()

        // Clear previous images
        second.hide()
        third.hide()
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    setInterval(cycleImages, 3000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a random hide and show from the three div's.You can specify the div number which should be visible or add any further condition.

HTML changes: i have added a common class "image"

```
<div class="image first">same image</div>
<div class="image second">same image</div>
<div class="image third">same image</div>
```

Jquery code :

```
    setInterval(function(){
      var max = 3;var min = 1;
      var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;

      $('.image:nth-child('+a+')').css('visibility','visible');
      $('.image').not(':nth-child('+a+')').css('visibility','hidden');

  //if you dont need the position intact just try
  //$('.image:nth-child('+a+')').show();
  //$('.image').not(':nth-child('+a+')').hide();
    },3000)
```

I hope this is what you were asking about.

check the working demo [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nitish1604/2e0akgy3/1/)

Comment: Firstly i don't need to hide whole divs. Colored div's are active always, i want to change only the image that's inside the div. Anyway this look something similar that i need. I tested it and it seems that 3rd div is not showing up.

Comment: Your code is not giving ever the third image. You don't have to do  `var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);` but only `var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * max  + min);`

Comment: Jsut change the selector to hide and show from 
  
  $('.image:nth-child('+a+')').find('img').css('visibility','visible');
  $('.image').not(':nth-child('+a+')').find('').css('visibility','hidden');

updated Demo 

http://jsfiddle.net/nitish1604/2e0akgy3/3/

Comment: It should be var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * max ) + min ; Thanks for the correction